# FastAPI with aiocache and Redis Couldn't set databases.backends.postgres.Record object

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, redis, fastapi

I'm trying to implement Redis on my endpoint using the aiocache library.
The first test I did with aiocache I used @cache without indicating any other service and everything worked. But when I tried to use Redis I see this error (the endpoint still returns the request)

```
ERROR:    Couldn't set [<databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb9f01d86a0>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb9f01d88b0>, <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb9f01d8a60>] in key app.api.authorget_authors()[], unexpected error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiocache/decorators.py", line 144, in set_in_cache
    await self.cache.set(key, value, ttl=self.ttl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiocache/base.py", line 61, in _enabled
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiocache/base.py", line 45, in _timeout
    return await asyncio.wait_for(func(self, *args, **kwargs), timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 483, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiocache/base.py", line 75, in _plugins
    ret = await func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiocache/base.py", line 265, in set
    ns_key, dumps(value), ttl=self._get_ttl(ttl), _cas_token=_cas_token, _conn=_conn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiocache/serializers/serializers.py", line 140, in dumps
    return json.dumps(value)
TypeError: <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb9f01d8a60> is not JSON serializable
```

The method is:

```py
@authors.get("/", response_model=List[AuthorOut])                                                                                                                                                                                        
@cached(                                                                                                
     ttl=100,                                                                                            
     cache=Cache.REDIS,
     endpoint="X.X.X.X", #my local ip
     serializer=JsonSerializer(),
     port=6379,
     namespace="main",
     #key="key",
 )
async def get_authors():
   return await db_manager.get_all_authors()
```

The whole environment is based on docker, 2 containers, 1 FastApi, 1 PostgreSQL and 1 Redis.

It seems evident that there is a problem with the object returned by the endpoint, so I ask you how can I pass such a complex object to Redis?

Following the aiochace documentation I have tried all the serializers present but without success.

My docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  book_service:
    build: ./book-service
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./book-service/:/app/
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=postgresql://book_db_username:book_db_password@book_db/book_db_dev
      - AUTHOR_SERVICE_HOST_URL=http://author_service:8000/api/v1/authors/
    depends_on:
      - book_db

  book_db:
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_book:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=book_db_username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=book_db_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=book_db_dev
  
  author_service:
    build: ./author-service
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./author-service/:/app/
    ports:
      - 8002:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URI=postgresql://author_db_username:author_db_password@author_db/author_db_dev
    depends_on:
      - author_db

  author_db:
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_author:/var/lib/postgres/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=author_db_username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=author_db_password
      - POSTGRES_DB=author_db_dev

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_config.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - author_service
      - book_service

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine
    volumes:
      #      - redis_data:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

    networks:
      node_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.4

networks:
  node_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16

volumes:
  postgres_data_book:
  postgres_data_author:
  redis_data:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says it all

```
TypeError: <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x7fb9f01d8a60> is not JSON serializable
```

The error lies in the fact that you are serializing the object in JSON for caching it that is not serializable in JSON.

I had a similar problem once, but found that fastAPI's encoder supports the `Record` object, while others don't. You can either return an object serialized via such encoder, or set it as encoder in the redis cache parameters. See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/#using-the-jsonable_encoder.

I did not test the following code, but it should be enough to give the idea of what I mean.

```
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

@authors.get("/", response_model=List[AuthorOut])                                                                                                                                                                                        
@cached(                                                                                                
     ttl=100,                                                                                            
     cache=Cache.REDIS,
     endpoint="X.X.X.X", #my local ip
     serializer=JsonSerializer(),
     port=6379,
     namespace="main",
     #key="key",
 )
async def get_authors():
   return jsonable_encoder(await db_manager.get_all_authors())
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can use redis_cache to access with RedisDB**

connection.py

```
from typing import Optional

from aioredis import Redis, create_redis_pool

#Create a RedisCache instance
class RedisCache:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.redis_cache: Optional[Redis] = None
        
    async def init_cache(self):
        self.redis_cache = await create_redis_pool("redis://localhost:6379/0?encoding=utf-8") #Connecting to database

    async def keys(self, pattern):
        return await self.redis_cache.keys(pattern)

    async def set(self, key, value):
        return await self.redis_cache.set(key, value)
    
    async def get(self, key):
        return await self.redis_cache.get(key)

    
    async def close(self):
        self.redis_cache.close()
        await self.redis_cache.wait_closed()


redis_cache = RedisCache()
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, applications
from uvicorn import run
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from connection import redis_cache



app = FastAPI(title="FastAPI with Redis")


async def get_all():
    return await redis_cache.keys('*')


@app.on_event('startup')
async def starup_event():
    await redis_cache.init_cache()


@app.on_event('shutdown')
async def shutdown_event():
    redis_cache.close()
    await redis_cache.wait_closed()

#root
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Redis": "FastAPI"}

#root > Get all keys from the redis DB
@app.get('/RedisKeys')
async def redis_keys():
    return await get_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run("main:app", port=3000, reload=True)
```

I am using uvicorn to access:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```